# Multiple details row plus symbols?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm attempting to create a details row on my backpack table, but I'm getting the following view:

[image]

The code I'm using to generate the plus symbol is:

```
$this->crud->enableDetailsRow();
$this->crud->allowAccess('details_row');
```

I'm unsure as to why theirs a duplicate expansion symbol within my type column?

Comment: what does enableDetailsRow and allowAccess code does?

Comment: Hmmm.... that's weird. (1) What version of Backpack\Crud are you using? You can find that out with ```php artisan backpack:base:version```. (2) Have you modified the ```list.blade.php``` file or ```datatables_logic.blade.php``` file?